# formula data doesn't show zero

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I am entering excel sheets that need to reference bar codes like 
014497020712
I know by using apostrophe I can get the zero to show 
but I also need to list check digit separate (2) and the bar code short that digit (01449702071)
I have thousands of items so I'm trying to use formulas like =RIGHT(B2,11) 
but this method doesn't show the zero proceeding (1449702071)
And again I have to type an apostrophe in the beginning of the fields.

Is there another trick?

Answer (score 2):

1. Format the field (column) so it always has the full length, including leading zeros. Format code would be "00000000000".
2. or format the column as 'Text'. Then you can do text functions on it, but not calculations.